# CXF 2.7.12's WSDL2Java does not generate @Addressing annotation

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, ws-addressing

I'm building client proxies with WSDL2Java. The web service I'm querying needs WSA policy enforced as stated in the WSDL.

Here is how I generate the code (Ant task)

```xml
<java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava">
    <arg value="-p" />
    <arg value="@{package}" />
    <arg value="-client" />
    <arg value="-exsh" />
    <arg value="true" />
    <arg value="-verbose" />
    <arg value="-mark-generated" />
    <arg value="-b" />
    <arg value="dev/jaxb-bindings.xml" />
    <arg value="-d" />
    <arg value="gen" />
    <arg value="@{wsdl}" />
    <classpath>
        <path refid="cxf.classpath" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Target WSDLs are:

- https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/DealService.svc?wsdl
- https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/UserService.svc?wsdl
- https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/PerformanceDataUploadService.svc?wsdl
- https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/PerformanceDataDownloadService.svc?wsdl

(Only the first two enforce WSA)

Fragment from `DealService`:

```xml
<wsdl:service name="DealService">
    <wsdl:port name="wsHttp_DealServiceEndPoint" binding="tns:wsHttp_DealServiceEndPoint">
        <soap12:address location="https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/DealService.svc" />
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            <wsa10:Address>https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.3/DealService.svc</wsa10:Address>
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Resulting annotated interface (`IDealService`) is missing the `@Addressing` annotation, which I must add manually

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://edwin.eurodw.eu/EDServices/2.2", name = "IDealService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2014-10-20T11:24:25.099+02:00", comments = "Apache CXF 2.7.12")
public interface IDealService {
```

### The question is

Since building annotated interfaces is part of an automated build process, how do I tell wsdl2java to use Addressing feature? I have the entire CXF runtime in my classpath

WSDLs are public so you can test yourself the generation (but not actual calls, since you need User Testing credentials)